# Console application string output to another web application text box

Tags: c#

I build a console application which uses a scanner to scan the QR code and output the values as strings in to a console application.

I have separate web application which uses this console output as a textbox input in each time user scans the QR code. I don't know how to make a connection between these two application since they run separately.

```
public static void InitializeSettings() {
            SerialPortManager _spManager = new SerialPortManager();
            SerialSettings mySerialSettings = _spManager.CurrentSerialSettings;

            _spManager.NewSerialDataRecieved += new EventHandler<SerialDataEventArgs>(_spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved);

            // use to initialize serial port settings
            mySerialSettings.PortName = "";
            mySerialSettings.BaudRate = ;
            mySerialSettings.DataBits = ;
            mySerialSettings.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
            mySerialSettings.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
            _spManager.CurrentSerialSettings = mySerialSettings;

            // Start thread to start listening
            Thread listenThread = new Thread( _spManager.StartListening);
            listenThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            listenThread.IsBackground = false;

            listenThread.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void _spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataEventArgs e)
        {
            string data = Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Data);
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Above code prints the QR value in the console. Any idea regarding this is more helpful.

Thanks

Comment: _"I have separate web application which uses this console output as a textbox input in each time user scans the QR code."_ Do you mean one you have open in a browser? Traditional barcode scanners typically connect as keyboards, so you could use something like `SendKeys` to send the barcode to the web currently active window/textbox.

Comment: @John thanks.Yes.I have web application which opens in a browser. But here I have to read the scanner output as a separate console application. How can I use 'SendKeys' to pass the data from console application to separate web application? How I can find the exact text box which I am referring in the web application?

Comment: I was more thinking you would select the textbox (as I selected this comment box to type this comment), and then the QR reader console app would simply use `SendKeys` to pass the contents of the QR code to whatever is the active window/textbox.

Comment: I can use  SendKeys.Send("^V") as a paste option. But how I get the console text output to the web application textbox?

Comment: Windows will take care of that for you, no? If I click on a textbox on any application, and then another application calls `SendKeys`, then it will write into the active textbox of whatever application is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, it would be better to setup your barcode scanner as a regular keyboard in your system; this will allow you to just focus on the textbox in your web page and it should receive the scanned code, usually followed by the `enter` key.

If that's not possible, and assuming that you can modify this web application and that you can only interact with your barcode scanner via a serial port (as I can see in your provided code), you could expose a http server from your console application, then your web application could connect to it, using web sockets or a pulling strategy via ajax, and listen for scanned codes that you can use to populate your textbox with and perform any other required action; you will also need to setup CORS on this http server to allow access from your web application domain.

If that http server idea sounds good to you, take a look a SignalR, it can help you to accomplish this; the nuget package name is: `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost`.

Some documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host